# Is $GL_2(\mathbb Z)\cdot X$ a dense subset of $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-actions

We know that the set $D=\{a+b\sqrt{2} \mid a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ because $D$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ that is not of the form $\alpha \mathbb Z$.

So, the following set $$\left\{(a+b\sqrt{2},c+d\sqrt{2}) \mid a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Z \right\}$$ is also dense in $\mathbb R^2$.

Here is my question : is it also true that the subset $$\left\{(a+b\sqrt{2},c+d\sqrt{2}) \mid a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Z, ad-bc=\pm 1 \right\}$$ is dense in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

If the answer is no, then can one find a vector $X\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $$\{MX \mid M\in GL_2(\mathbb Z)\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}X \mid a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Z, ad-bc=\pm 1\right\}$$ is dense in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: What is the motivation of the question? I find it strange that you consider this set as opposed to, say, $GL_2({\bf Z}[\sqrt 2])$.

Comment: My question is related to the action of $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ on the real plane. I would like to understand the orbits and precisely those coming from of a point with irrational coordinates.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense in hindsight. :)

Comment: @Crostul: $L_X$ is not a subgroup, it does not contain the identity element $0$ if $X\neq 0$ for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the answer is positive. You can get a dense orbit from the subgroup $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acting on any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that isn't a scalar multiple of a vector in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. See an elementary proof by S.G. Dani and Arnaldo Nogueira [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X09000456). I'm not sure if there are proofs from scratch that are more brief.

Comment: Very nice, thank you !